# Django : Find 'difference' between two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Say I have two models as follows -

```
class DID_Definition_Model(models.Model):   # DID to Region-Carrier Mapping
    did_number= models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[alphanumeric], primary_key=True)




class DID_Number_Assignment_Model(models.Model):       #DID Number Assignment
    did_selector = models.ForeignKey(DID_Definition_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

I want to report on the 'difference' in entries, (possibly via difference method)  which may be available in DID_Definition_Model did_number field but not in DID_Number_Assignment_Model did_selector field.

In my failing attempt my thought process was to create a query which will contain all entries of did_number. Then repeat the same procedure to get all entries of did_selector. Finally compare the two queries using difference method.
But I kind of got stuck at the first stage -

- > > > **getattr(DID_Definition_Model, did_number)
  > > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
  > > >       File "", line 1, in 
  > > >       NameError: name 'did_number' is not defined ***
  > > >       But the above is simply not possible as did_number is a valid field of DID_Definition_Model

Any guidance will be helpful as I have been through multiple message boards and could not seem to find any way out.

Comment: By "difference" do you mean to get all `DID_Definition_Model.did_number` where there is no corresponding row in `DID_Number_Assignment_Model`?

Comment: Correct, that is what I wanted. I was actually looking at the following link to get more sense of available methods-
https://djangobook.com/mdj2-advanced-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all objects where there are no related objects, you can use `relationship__isnull=True`.

```
defs_with_no_assignments = DID_Definition_Model.objects.filter(
    did_number_assignment_model__isnull=True
)
```

To get just the values, you can use `values_list`

```
did_numbers_with_no_assignments.values_list('did_number', flat=True)
```